# C function prototype: \\char *strinv(const char *s);

Tags: c, prototype, c-strings, dereference, function-declaration

```
char *strinv(const char *s); //that's the given prototype
```

I'm a bit insecure about the *strinv part. Does it mean that the function is automatically dereferenced when called? Or that the function is defined as a pointer?

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: It means the return type is a `char *`.

Comment: `Does it mean that the function is automatically dereferenced when called?` - can you elaborate what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function declaration

```
char * strinv(const char *s);
```

declares a function that has the return type `char *`. For example the function can allocate dynamically memory for a string and return pointer to that string.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function for example can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * strinv(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *t = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( t != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        for ( ; i != n; i++ ) t[i] = s[n-i-1];

        t[i] = '\0';
    }

    return t;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Hello Worlds!";

    char *t = strinv( s );

    puts( t );

    free( t );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
!sdlroW olleH
```

A declaration of a pointer to the function can look the foolowing way

```
char * ( *fp )( const char * ) = strinv;
```

To dereference the pointer and call the pointed function you can write

```
( *fp )( s );
```

though it is enough to write

```
fp( s );
```